# prevent saving when wpf date picker has an invalid date mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, datepicker

I have been searching this forumn now and I can't find what I am really looking for. I am trying to use the mvvm pattern and on my save button I am using a relay command:

```
<Button x:Name="_Save" Grid.Row="12" Margin="21,17,5,10" Content="_Save" FontSize="12" FontWeight="SemiBold" Width="75" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={
         RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
```

and VM code

```
public ICommand SaveCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_saveCommand == null)
        {
            _saveCommand = new RelayCommand(
                param => this.Save(param),
                param => this.CanSave
                );
        }
        return _saveCommand;
    }
}
bool CanSave
{
    get
    {

        _validator = new CRValidation(this);
        return _validator.IsValid;
        return true;

    }
}
```

However I want to prevent saving when someone enters invalid text in my date picker. i.e. letters, or 1/1/0002 something like that.  Currently when that data is entered the datepicker returns null instead of the invalid data and proceeds to save. I have tried binding to both the text properties and selected date property. How can I evaluate a datepicker when it contains invalid data while still using the mvvm pattern?

```
<DatePicker Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" SelectedDate="{Binding PeriodEndDate, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></DatePicker>
```

Comment: You can't. If the user enters an invalid date and ignore any UI warnings, then that's their problem. The invalid date won't be passed to any data bound property and so your view model will never know.

Comment: So there are no workarounds?

Comment: In development, it is a rare situation when there is really no way to do something. However, if there is a way, I'm not aware of it. Wait for a few days and see if you get any answers... then you'll know.

Comment: Little late now but I will say it anyway: What about actually doing the validation in the ViewModel (and obviously not passing it along to the Model if it's invalid). That way the ViewModel would no and could potentially prevent saving, yes?